# Why i can't retrieve username and password from Firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to login using username and password that is stored in Firebase realtime database. But my code does not work. I include my database picture and code. Please help me.

This is database image:

[image]

This is my main activity code MainActivity.java

```
databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Client");
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Query query = databaseReference.child("Client").orderByChild("username").equalTo(editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim());
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Users usersBean = user.getValue(Users.class);
                            if (usersBean.password.equals(editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is my users java class Users.java

```
    public class Users {
    String email;
    String id;
    String password;
    String username;

    public Users() {

    }

    public Users(String email, String id, String password, String username) {
        this.email = email;
        this.id = id;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Client");
```

to

```
databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

There is no need to get a reference of the `Client` node since you are using a call to `.child("Client")` in your query.

**Edit:**

To solve the error you get now according to your comment, plase change the type of your `id` property in your `Users` class from `String` to `long` and the getter and setter like this:

```
public class Users {
    String email;
    long id;
    String password;
    String username;

    public Users() {

    }

    public Users(String email, long id, String password, String username) {
        this.email = email;
        this.id = id;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Comment: not working.when i clicked button app is stopped.@Alex Mamo

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Here is logcat; https://drive.google.com/open?id=11kpO1jHwwnokIEuf2B1a-FZrmPPJe6bL ..@Alex Mamo

Comment: Not work...i try adding indexOn still failed..please implement it in your IDE and run..@Alex Mamo

Comment: "Not work" doesn't help. Why is not working? Till now, we fixed two errors and we usually stick to one question at a time. What is the problem now? Do you have any other errors?

Comment: when click button logcat show: adding .indexOn:"id" to improvement better performance..so i add this but still show me same message.@Alex Mamo

Comment: This sounds as a third issue which is not related with the first ones and for which I recommend you to post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.