# Trying to add password to Firebase RealTime Database, but it doesn't show up?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I know Firebase Auth exists, but this is for a school project where I have to implement my own hash for the passwords.

I'm registering users to the Realtime Database, it gets added in the correct format, but "password" doesn't show up. Is there a way to make it show up?

Heres some example code

```
public void  registerUser (String name, String email, String password)
{
    Intent toWelcome = new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
    String id = mDatabase.push().getKey();
    if (type.equals("Admin")) {
        Person user = new Admin(id, email, password, name);
        mDatabase.child("Person").child("Admin").child(id).setValue(user);
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Admin account already created.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if (type.equals("Patient"))
    {
        Person user = new Patient(id, email, password, name);
        mDatabase.child("Person").child("Patient").child(id).setValue(user);
    }
    else if (type.equals("Employee"))
    {
        Person user = new Employee(id, email, password, name);
        mDatabase.child("Person").child("Employee").child(id).setValue(user);
    }

    toWelcome.putExtra("name", name);
    toWelcome.putExtra("role", type);
    startActivity(toWelcome);
}
```

Here is what shows up in my database:

[image: database example]

Any ideas?

Comment: Show your `Person` model

Comment: Show us the content of your `Person` class. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: ```public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String name;

    public Person (String id, String email, String password, String name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
    }
}```

@AlexMamo @Md. Asaduzzaman

Comment: I've figured it out, my Person class did not have the getPassword method, so I guess Firebase didn't maintain that field. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain it is supposed to show you the passwords? Servers are normally very reluctant to display such things even to admins. It may be a security feature. As an admin, you can reset a password, but not necessarily be able to see a password. You did mention it was a RealTime Database.

Comment: The guy in this link can do it, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334387/why-i-cant-retrieve-username-and-password-from-firebase-realtime-database)